# Ensuring object running a long task doesn't get re instantiated

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a WinForms application that gets Car data from a Sqlite database file which is generated by a CSV file from a WebService, and the related Parts for each Car. When instanced, the Car class populates all properties from the database and gets a lot of data from a WebService that takes about 30 seconds to finish so I just call an async Task after populating the database properties and let it run asyncronously. After the web service returns all data and all work is done, the instance is saved in a List that works like an internal cache.

All works well until the user makes an operation on a Part which requires the property ParentCar to be returned while the WebService method is still running, causing a new Car to be instantiated and re polling the web service as many times the property is requested while the Car doesn't exist on the cache list. This stops as soon as the first instance finishes processing but all changes will be overwritten every time the next instances finish.

I'm struggling to find a way to ensure that a Car is only instanced one time without blocking the UI during the application life time, any ideas?

This is the code that I currently have:

```
public class Car
{
    private List<Part> _parts = new List<Part>();

    public string Id { get; private set; }
    public int DbIndex
    {
        get { return DbClass.GetCarIndexById(Id); }
    }
    public ReadOnlyCollection<Part> Parts { get => _parts.AsReadOnly(); }

    public Car(System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader sQLiteDataReader)
    {
        // Code to Load all properties from sQLiteDataReader

        Task.Run(() => LongRuningWebServiceTask());
    }

    private async Task LongRuningWebServiceTask
    {
        // Long running code that will populate even more properties

        SaveToInternalDb();
    }

    private void SaveToInternalDb()
    {
        if (DbIndex > -1)
            DbClass.UpdateCarData(this);
        else
            DbClass.AddCar(this);
    }

    public void RelateParts(IEnumerable<Part> parts)
    {
        _parts.AddRange(parts);
    }

    ~Car()
    {
        SaveToInternalDb();
    }
}

public class Part
{
    public string ParentCarId { get; private set; }
    public Car ParentCar
    {
        get
        {
            Task getCar = DbClass.GetCarById(ParentCarId);
            getCar.Wait();
            return getCar.Result;
        }
    }
}

public static class DbClass
{
    private static SQLiteConnection sqlConn;
    private readonly string sqlFile = "pathToDbFile";
    private static List<Car> CarCache = new List<Car>();

    public static async Task<Car> GetCarById(string> carId, bool ignoreCache = false)
    {
        Car foundCar = null;
        if (!ignoreCache)
            foundCar = CarCache.Find(s => s.Id == carId);

        if (foundCar == null)
        {
            try
            {
                string sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM all_Cars WHERE Car = '{0}';", carId);
                using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, sqlConn))
                {
                    using (SQLiteDataReader reader = (SQLiteDataReader)await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                    {
                        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                            foundCar = new Car(reader));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                string m = e.Message;
            }

            if (foundCar != null)
            {
                var partsList = await GetPartsByCarId(carId);
                if (partsList.Count > 0)
                    Car.RelateParts(partsList);

                if (!ignoreCache)
                {
                    if (foundCar.DbIndex == -1)
                        CarCache.Add(foundCar);
                }
            }
        }

        return foundCar;
    }

    public static async Task<List<Part>> GetPartsByCarId(string carId)
    {
        List<Part> foundParts = new List<Part>();

        int index = GeCarIndexById(carId);
        Car foundCar = index > -1 ? CarCache[index] : null;
        if (foundCar != null)
            foundParts = await GetPartsByCarId(carId);

        return foundParts;
    }

    public static void InitiateSqlConnection()
    {
        if (sqlConn == null)
        {
            sqlConn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + sqlFile.FullName + ";Version=3;");
            try
            {
                sqlConn.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var m = e.Message;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(sqlConn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Broken || sqlConn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                sqlConn.Open();
        }
    }

    public static int GetCarIndexById(string carId)
    {
        int index = -1;
        for(int c = 0; c < CarCache.Count;c++)
        {
            if(CarCache[c].Id == carId)
            {
                index = c;
                break;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }

    public static void AddCar(Car car)
    {
        CarCache.Add(car);
    }

    public static void UpdateCarData(Car car)
    {
        if(car != null)
        {
            int index = car.DbIndex;
            if(index > -1)
                CarCache[index] = car;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use Task.Run() in your constructor.  Have a private constructor and expose a `public static Task<Car>` method that takes care of instantiating the object for you

Comment: It's a little hard to follow all of what you have going on there, and there is probably a better pattern for doing this. One thing you could do is replace the `List<Car> CarCache` with a `ConcurrentDictionary<int, Task<Car>>` and using what @maccettura suggested have a static method that returns a `Task<Car>` that can be awaited. You store those in your cache. (and you use a dictionary to look up by id because it would have quicker lookups than searching the whole list every time).

Comment: Honestly your Car class should just be a POC (just have the properties).  You should have a CarService that takes care of the database queries and returns to you a nice Car object.  That way your data access logic is separate from your actual model.  You seem to have a _lot_ of deadlocking potential with your code

Comment: You also have a pretty blatant SQL injection vulnerability.  Dont concatenate/format strings for SQL queries, **use parameterized queries**

Comment: @maccettura how would you suggest doing the CarService class? The ConcurrentDictionary implementation seems preety neat since the ids are unique... Sorry I still have a lot to learn, if you could point me some documentation would be great!

Comment: @HeD_pE Are you using the ConcurrentDictionary as a cache?

Comment: @maccettura no, I'm using a List<Car> as the example shows. I was just saying I liked the idea

Comment: @HeD_pE ah I see.  Well you have quite a lot of things I would change so its too much to dive into here.  ConcurrentDictionary is useful for multithreading because it is thread safe.  I wouldnt worry about all that yet.  I would start by creating a `Car` and `Part` class that literally just has the constructor and properties.  Then create a `CarService` and `PartService` class that handles the specific data operations you need per type. Both of those classes should inherit or use a common Data access class (the class that actually talks to your database).  Remember to keep your code SOLID

Comment: @HeD_pE You want to keep your individual pieces separate.  So the "model" should not care how it gets its data, it should just _represent_ the data.  The service should not care about what data provider you use, it should only care about what it needs to, like having a "get by id" function or "get all", etc.  Then your data access class should have an interface abstraction so that you can swap out data implementations later if you need to (look into dependency injection).

Comment: I had already thought about that but the problem is that the implementation would take a lot of time that is currently allocated to other projects like that LongRunningWebServiceTask which is actually a Telnet client from scratch, it would undoubdtfully benefit from these changes... The problem is that my boss doesn't understand those benefits ;(